# adding subview to superview of custom class isn't working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to learn how to make a custom class that can add subviews to it's superview and believe the code I have below should work, but it's not and I don't understand enough to figure out why. It builds successfully and runs through adding the subview but I never see it on my simulator. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

mainviewcontroller.m imports #alerts.h and tries to run

```
Alerts* al = [[Alerts alloc] initWithFrame:[self.view bounds]];

[al throwBottomAlert:@"message" withTitle:@"Title Test"];
```

and in my custom class...

header file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Alerts : UIAlertView

- (void)throwBottomAlert:(NSString*)message withTitle:(NSString*)title;


@end
```

implementation file

```
#import "Alerts.h"

@implementation Alerts

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)throwBottomAlert:(NSString*)message withTitle:(NSString*)title {

    UIView* alertView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[self bounds]];
    alertView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    [self.superview addSubview:alertView];
    [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:alertView];

}
```

Comment: apologies the subclassing of UIAlertView was completely accidental I didn't notice it and think autocorrect got me or something. I meant to have "Alerts" as UIView. After that revelation from Jeffery it became clear Ramshad had the second piece of the puzzle which was to pass the parentview along with it thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder about UIAlertView Subclassing.

Developer.Apple clearly says

> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be modified.

After ignoring the subclassing, Im going to give an answer below.

In your code,`self.superview` not refers `mainviewcontroller`

Because you just created an object of `Alerts` class in `mainviewcontroller`.

`Alerts` class will not have any view hierarchy with `mainviewcontroller`.

For doing this, you have to pass the `mainviewcontroller` to `Alerts` class either using `property` or `method parameter`.

**Example:**

**mainviewcontroller**

```
Alerts* al = [[Alerts alloc] initWithFrame:[self.view bounds]];

[al throwBottomAlert:@"message" withTitle:@"Title Test" ParentView:self.view];
```

**Alerts**

```
- (void)throwBottomAlert:(NSString*)message withTitle:(NSString*)title ParentView:(UIView *)parentView

{
    UIView* alertView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
    alertView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [parentView addSubview:alertView];
    [parentView bringSubviewToFront:alertView];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems here. I'll start with the worst new first. Subclassing `UIAlertView` is not supported and not really a good idea.

> ### Subclassing Notes
>
> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.

— [UIAlertView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)

The next piece of bad news, `-initWithFrame:` is not `UIAlertView`'s designated initializer and should not be used. You need to use `-initWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:`.

Finally, the superview of an existing `UIAlertView` is a `_UIAlertNormalizingOverlayWindow`. That `_UIAlertNormalizingOverlayWindow` is a subtype of `UIWindow` and has no superview. This means the alert you are seeing does not exist in the same window that all of your app views.